# MySQL replace IN with EXISTS, edited query is much more expensive

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization, exists

I have this query:

```
SELECT points.subject_id, SUM(points_in_round) 
AS points_in_round 
FROM points, subjects 
WHERE subjects.subject_id = points.subject_id 
AND subjects.subject_kind_id = 'businessman' 
AND points.subject_id IN
(SELECT subject_id FROM residents 
WHERE economic_id = 'USA' AND round_number = 1)
GROUP BY points.subject_id 
ORDER BY points_in_round DESC
```

I want to replace the IN clausule by EXIST.
I rewrote the query like this:

```
SELECT points.subject_id, SUM(points_in_round) 
AS points_in_round 
FROM points, subjects 
WHERE subjects.subject_id = points.subject_id 
AND subjects.subject_kind_id = 'businessman' 
AND EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM residents 
WHERE economic_id = 'USA' AND round_number = 1
AND points.subject_id = residents.subject_id)
GROUP BY points.subject_id 
ORDER BY points_in_round DESC
```

I get the same results, but the Execution plan says that **Query cost of edited query is 3100, while the Query cost of original query was 290.**

Where am I wrong?

Thanks everyone

Comment: I would replace `EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM residents` with `EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM residents` but besides that seems fine to me

Comment: It is still the same, when I did that, the query is still so much expensive.

Comment: Which table is `points_in_round` in?  You have an ambiguity -- two meanings of `points_in_round` - one as a column, one as an alias.  I don't know which one the `ORDER BY` is acting on.  Please change that alias.

Comment: And please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT...` for each query.  Where does "Query cost" come from?

Answer (score 1):

We do not know what indexes exist on your tables. Try the following query and add appropriate indexes if needed:

```
SELECT points.subject_id, SUM(points_in_round) AS points_in_round 
FROM points
LEFT JOIN subjects 
  ON subjects.subject_id = points.subject_id 
LEFT JOIN residents
  ON residents.subject_id = points.subject_id
WHERE subjects.subject_kind_id = 'businessman' 
  AND economic_id = 'USA' 
  AND round_number = 1
GROUP BY points.subject_id 
ORDER BY points_in_round DESC
```